# Set text style to a specific platform in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text

I'm using unicode characters but I'd like to control how they're displayed on different platforms. I'd like them to look the same on any platform. Is there a way to achieve this? I'd like them to look like in the first picture (I don't want emojis to be displayed).

The code where I'm drawing the text is here:

```
  final ui.ParagraphBuilder paragraphBuilder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(
  ui.ParagraphStyle(
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  ),
)..addText(text);
final ui.Paragraph paragraph = paragraphBuilder.build()
  ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: 20));
canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, offset);
```

[image: This is how I'd like them to look]
[This is how they look in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnpHp.jpg)
[image: This is how they look on Android]

Comment: "I'd like them to look the same on any platform". Do they look different on different platforms by default?

Comment: Yes, they look like in the pictures

Comment: Can you post your code that you use to show the unicode chars

Comment: Just added it (and the characters are already there, lines 19-30)

Comment: you can always try to use images instead

Comment: That’s not what I asked